# Angular2 - app/my-component.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'

Tags: angular

I learn angular2. Installed node.js, npm, typescript.

I run `npm start`

display errors:

```
app/my-component.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
```

**my-component.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
        This is my component!
    `
})
export class MyComponentComponent {

}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

I cant undestand why cant found angular2/core?
Can you help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
@angular/core
```

instead will solve the error.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: yes. work. But why dont work with "angular2/core"? I copy from documentation

Comment: Because directry name the module included was changed. But I don't know that was changed.