# Blank Page with ‘@angular2/core’ instead of ‘@angular/core’

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I try to import my component from `@angular2/core` instead of `@angular/core` the whole page doesn't work anymore. But If I use `@angular/core` I get compile errors because `directives: [MapDirective]` is not valid.

Any clue on how to fix this?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MapDirective } from '../../components/map/map';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  directives: [MapDirective]
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

Comment: when angular was in beta you could import as import {Component} from 'angular2/core';  now you can only import from @angular  check your node_modules folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - app/my-component.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528940/angular2-app-my-component-component-ts1-25-error-ts2307-cannot-find-module)

Comment: I found a solution for the Directive, so the question is solved for me

Comment: In Ionic2 the usage of Directives changed completely - a very good tutorial can be found here: http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-directive-in-ionic-2-parallax-header/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how my page looks in ionic 2:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

there is no such thing as:

```
import {Component} from '@angular2/core';
```

Comment: But if I would like to use Directives in a Component it doesn't work with just @angular/core instead of @angular2/core. WebStorm shows me compile errors. With angular2/core I don't have compile errors but a blank page. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I am also using Webstorm and actually right now I am working with ionic 2  at this very moment :)  first check  the folder node_modules and see if you have a folder named @angular if you  have one then restart webstorm also check your typescript settings in your webstorm sometimes  it fails to properly load

Answer (score 2):

With 2.0.0-rc.0, Angular2 team changed the directory name from angular2 to @angular

> To import various symbols please adjust the paths in the following way:
>
> angular2/core -> @angular/core

Here's the full changelog: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-rc0-2016-05-02